# JPA Container persistence unit Vs JPA Non-container persistence unit

Tags: java, jpa

I am new to JPA and in many resources of JPA I encounter these two term(Container persistence unit and Non-container persistence unit) but I can not understand differences.Can anybody help me understand these phrases? what is the container ?is it something like 
Tomcat?

Answer (score 1):

'Container' in this context means an EJB container, which is usually provided by a Java EE compliant application server.

Since Tomcat is not Java EE compliant, it is not a 'container' in the sense of the JPA spec. [Tom EE](http://tomee.apache.org/) however provides such a container as do other Java EE servers. Oracle provides a [complete list of compliant servers](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javaee/overview/compatibility-jsp-136984.html).

The main difference is that in a container you can use JTA resources like transactions and a transaction-scoped `EntityManager`. Without a container you have to use `ÈntityTransaction` and an `EXTENDED` `EntityManager`.

Answer (score 0):

In the attribute transaction-type can take one of the 2 values "RESOURCE_LOCAL" or "JTA".

JTA - Works on an application server environment. Transaction managed by the application server.

RESOURCE_LOCAL - You managed the transaction with your code. You can use this to work standalone during the development / testing phase.